# Pandas loc by list

Tags: python, pandas

I’m not anywhere near a computer right now so I can’t test this out, but can I .loc by a list?

As in, I regularly do

```
df.loc[df[‘col’] == ‘this’]
```

Can I do

```
df.loc[df[[‘col1’, ‘col2’]] == [‘this’, ‘that’]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can do something like:

```
df.loc[df[['col1', 'col2']].eq(['this', 'that']).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do:

```
df.loc[df['col1'] == 'this' & df['col2'] == 'that']
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `tuple`

```
df.loc[df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(tuple,1) == ('this', 'that')]
```